# Delete a branch in github using GraphQL mutations

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'd like to delete a github branch using a GraphQL mutation, but I haven't found enough information regarding the [`deleteRef`](https://developer.github.com/v4/input_object/deleterefinput/) command. Using the [GraphQL explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) I came up with this nonsense:

```
mutation {
  deleteRef(input: {refId: "my-branch"}) {
    __typename
  }
}
```

I don't know yet how to add repository information for the mutation to have any meaning, and the only reason I included `__typename` was because the `deleteRef` block couldn't be left empty. How do I fix this mutation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return nothing in that mutation since it's not of type `Void`. You need to define a mutation like the following :

```graphql
mutation DeleteBranch($branchRef: ID!) {
  deleteRef(input: {refId: $branchRef}) {
    __typename
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

In the [explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) you can define queries and mutations and choose which one to execute when you hit the button. A full example in the explorer would be :

```graphql
query GetBranchID {
  repository(name: "test-repo", owner: "bertrandmartel") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", first: 100) {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}

mutation DeleteBranch($branchRef: ID!) {
  deleteRef(input: {refId: $branchRef}) {
    __typename
    clientMutationId
  }
}
```

with variables:

```json
{
  "branchRef": "MDM6UmVmMjQ5MDU0NzQ0Om1hc3Rlcg=="
}
```

You can do the following in the explorer :

- perform the `GetBranchID` query
- copy paste the reference in the `branchRef` variable
- perform the `DeleteBranch`

Without the explorer, here's how it would look using [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```python
import requests

repo_name = "YOUR_REPO"
repo_owner = "YOUR_USERNAME"
token = "YOUR_TOKEN"

query = """
query {
  repository(name: \"""" + repo_name + """\", owner: \"""" + repo_owner + """\") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", first: 100) {
      nodes {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

resp = requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', 
    json={ "query": query},
    headers= {"Authorization": f"Token {token}"}
)
body = resp.json()

for i in body["data"]["repository"]["refs"]["nodes"]:
    print(i["name"], i["id"])

chosenBranchId = input("Enter a branch ID: ")

query = """
mutation {
  deleteRef(input: {refId: \"""" + chosenBranchId + """\"}) {
    __typename
    clientMutationId
  }
}
"""

resp = requests.post('https://api.github.com/graphql', 
    json={ "query": query},
    headers= {"Authorization": f"Token {token}"}
)
print(resp.json())
```